# Pressing f ^ ( - 1 ) on my keyboard comes out as f⁽-1) and not f^(-1), which I want (danish keymap)

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

When I want to write f^(-1) on my keyboard it comes out as f⁽⁻¹⁾. More precisely:

Pressing ^ on my keyboard "exponentiates" the next letter I press, such that:

Pressing **f ^ ( ^ - ^ 1 ^ )** on my keyboard gives **f⁽⁻¹⁾**

Since I write papers in LaTeX, this is unacceptable to me. I want to press

**f ^  ( - 1 )** and get exactly **f^(-1)**, but instead I get **f⁽-1)**

**I'm on Ubuntu 19.10 and when I installed it I chose the danish keymap.**

**Note: It does so in every editor/program I've tried: gedit, Terminal, LibreOffice, AskUbuntu, firefox, everywhere.**

Comment: Actually, I learned something new! My US Int keyboard layout does the same. For US keyboard, there are variants, including one without dead key. So check whether there are variants for Danish as well that does not include dead keys.

Comment: I can reproduce in gedit.

Comment: .. spanish layout

Comment: My installation is out-of-the-box. No plugins. I get the same result in Terminal.

Comment: I am using plain US English keyboard, not the one with dead keys. This seems like a "feature" of the specific keyboard layouts. Try adding US English layout may be?

Comment: Changing to US English Keyboard solves the problem, so you are right. It must be a (stupid) feature of the danish keymap.

Comment: Pressing ^ twice stops it from making the next letter into a superscript in the danish keymap. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I can replicate this in my spanish layout, found the trick:

After writing the <kbd>^</kbd> symbol, press the <kbd>Space bar</kbd>, to disable the superscript.

Comment: That works in the danish layout aswell.

Answer (score 1):

**Note that this is about the danish keymap!**

Pressing ^ twice stops it from making the next letter into a superscript.

Apparently, other keymaps, such as US English Keyboard, don't have this "feature".

Comment: I tried "Danish (no dead keys)" keyboard layout and it does not have this feature. It took me a while to find the ^ on this layout though.